# How can a pringles can act as WiFi booster?

Tags: telecommunications

How does a wifi transciever placed inside a Pringles can act as a wifi signal booster. I saw this trick on Mr robot TV series.
Do WiFi routers emit less power than GSM or LTE. I know for :

GSM - 2W (33dbm)

LTE - 200mW (23dbm)

Comment: Not booster, directional (c)antenna

Comment: Wifi: 100mW when using 2.4 GHz. The 5 GHz band uses more power.

Comment: @TurboJ that statement is as far as I know wrong, and even if it isn't, the amount of power you may use depends on local jurisdiction, so you certainly can't make general statements like that.

Comment: What are limits set by FCC?

Comment: @ObsessionWithElectricity https://www.air802.com/fcc-rules-and-regulations.html or https://w.wol.ph/2015/08/28/maximum-wifi-transmission-power-country/ ; not sure how useful that is on its own though.

Comment: How is GSM or LTE even related to your question? What are you actually asking about here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As PlasmaHH says, it doesn't boost the total power - it can't, it's a passive device. Instead it makes the antenna much more directional. Signal behind or to the side will be much weaker. Usually you'll use them in pairs to make a link between two buildings.

Very similar principles to the directional reflectors in flashlights or car headlights.